# How to format the function body when using toString()

Tags: javascript, formatting, google-chrome-devtools, firebug, console.log

Let's say I have this function from a minified JavaScript file:

```
function fn(){console.log('Lorem');console.log('Ipsum');}
```

I would like to get a pretty print, indented version when calling:

```
console.log(fn.toString());
```

Expected output :

```
function fn() {
    console.log('Lorem');
    console.log('Ipsum');
}
```

Instead of:

```
function fn(){console.log('Lorem');console.log('Ipsum');}
```

Anyway to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript does not have a built-in function to do this. So, if you want to do pretty printing programmatically, you'll have to do it manually.
To get the function´s source, there is a non-standard [`Function.prototype.toSource()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toSource) function, which is only supported by Firefox, though. A very simple pretty-print function covering your example is:

```
function prettyPrint(source) {
  let formattedSource = fn.toSource ? fn.toSource() : "";

  // Add line breaks after curly braces and semicolons
  formattedSource = formattedSource.replace(/([{};])/g, "$1\n");

  // Add space after opening curly brace
  formattedSource = formattedSource.replace(/(\S)\{/g, "$1 {");

  // Indent lines ending with a semicolon
  formattedSource = formattedSource.replace(/^(.*?);/gm, "    $1;");

  return formattedSource;
}

console.log(prettyPrint(fn));
```

Having said the above, the different developer tools have integrated options to pretty print the JavaScript sources within their debuggers.

**Firebug:**

[image: Firebug pretty print button]

**Firefox DevTools:**

[image: Firefox DevTools pretty print button]

**Chrome DevTools:**

[image: Chrome DevTools pretty print button]

Answer (score 0):

There is the `js-beautify` library which does a really good job in pretty printing JS code

http://jsbeautifier.org/

https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify

```
// Script inclusion
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open('GET', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.6.4/beautify.js', false);
xmlHttp.send(null);
var jsCode = xmlHttp.responseText;

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = jsCode;
document.head.appendChild(script);

// Usage
function fn(){console.log('Lorem');console.log('Ipsum');}
js_beautify(fn.toString());

// Output
function fn() {
    console.log('Lorem');
    console.log('Ipsum');
}
```